# Docker compose ftpd-server access from host

Tags: docker, docker-compose, ftp-client

I'm using trying to access a ftpd-server from the host

Using `ftp localhost` or `ftp <my_ip>`

But I'm getting `ftp: connect: Connection refused`

```
version: '3'

services:
  ftpd-server:
    container_name: ftpd-server
    image: stilliard/pure-ftpd:hardened
    ports:
      - 21:21
      - 20:20
      - 30000-30009:30000-30009
    volumes:
      - './ftp/data:/home/username/'
      - './ftp/pass:/etc/pure-ftpd/passwd'
    environment:
      PUBLICHOST: "0.0.0.0"
      FTP_USER_NAME: "user"
      FTP_USER_PASS: "pass"
      FTP_USER_HOME: "/home/username"
    restart: always
```

Since I'm using `PUBLICHOST: "0.0.0.0"` and port forward `21:21` I was expecting to be able to connect.

Docker Log

```
Removing ftpd-server ... done
Removing network mytest_default
No stopped containers
Creating network "mytest_default" with the default driver
Creating ftpd-server ... 
Creating ftpd-server ... done
Attaching to ftpd-server
ftpd-server    | Creating user...
ftpd-server    | Password: 
ftpd-server    | Enter it again: 
ftpd-server    | Setting default port range to: 30000:30009
ftpd-server    | Setting default max clients to: 5
ftpd-server    | Setting default max connections per ip to: 5
ftpd-server    | Starting Pure-FTPd:
ftpd-server    |   pure-ftpd  -l puredb:/etc/pure-ftpd/pureftpd.pdb -E -j -R -P 0.0.0.0 -s -A -j -Z -H -4 -E -R -G -X -x   -p 30000:30009 -c 5 -C 5
```

How can I achieve to connect from host machine to my ftp server on the container?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add `network_mode: host` to your service definition to make it work.

```yaml
services:
  ftpd-server:
    # ...
    network_mode: host
    # ...
```

Then test with:

```
$ ftp -p localhost 21
Connected to localhost.
220---------- Welcome to Pure-FTPd [privsep] [TLS] ----------
220-You are user number 1 of 5 allowed.
220-Local time is now 16:04. Server port: 21.
220-This is a private system - No anonymous login
220 You will be disconnected after 15 minutes of inactivity.
```

Answer (score 0):

A working example on my side is as following:

```
version: "1.0"
services:
  ftpd-server:
    image: stilliard/pure-ftpd:hardened
    ports:
      - "21:21"
      - "30000-30009:30000-30009"
    volumes:
      - './ftp/data:/home/username/'
      - './ftp/pass:/etc/pure-ftpd/passwd'
    environment:
      PUBLICHOST: "0.0.0.0"
      FTP_USER_NAME: "username"
      FTP_USER_PASS: "changeme!"
      FTP_USER_HOME: "/home/username"
    restart: always
```

Adding line of "network_mode: host" would cause following error with latest Docker installation (for my case it's Docker version 20.10.13, build a224086 on a Windows 10 OS with WSL2 support):

```
"host" network_mode is incompatible with port_bindings
```

It's a guarding facility involved in newer version of docker to avoid mis-configuration of ports, check following link for details: https://forums.docker.com/t/docker-errors-invalidargument-host-network-mode-is-incompatible-with-port-bindings/103492.